# Alterar valor de elementos do HTML utilizando o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu estou tentando mudar valores de inputs de formulários em uma página HTML utilizando somento a tag <?php no inicio do site. Meu objetivo é não poluir o site com tags <?php sempre que eu precisar alterar algum elemento da página EX:

```
<input id= "IDname" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['algo']; ?>" />
```

Isso me parece muito feio, sem tratamento de valores e bem poluído.

Eu pensei em uma solução, mas não sei bem se funciona, alguém poderia analisar meu código abaixo e me dizer se é uma boa prática, se não, poderia me falar qual seria o melhor modo de se fazer?

```php
  <?php
  function setInputValueFromPost($varPost, $elementID){
    if(isset($_POST[$varPost])){
      echo '<script> document.getElementById(' .$elementID. ').value =' .$_POST[$varPost]. '; </script>'
    }
  }

  setInputValueFromPost('nome', 'IDnome');
  />

<input id= "IDnome" type="text" name="name" />
```

Comment: Olá, sua lógica foi muito boa, porem não é uma boa pratica misturar linguagens front e back (no caso PHP e Javascript). Diria que em termos de boa pratica seria melhor separar o backend do frontend e o frontend solitar as informações ao backend já tratadas, porem esse é um nivel que um projeto pequeno não precisa usar.

Comment: Pesquisa um pouco sobre sistema de templates, alguns exemplos: twig, blade, smarty, mustache, volt, ...

Answer (score 0):

A solução que você pensou é o que pode ser chamado de "gambiarra monstra".
Há formas melhores de organizar essa questão, uma é usando templates como mencionado por um colega, como TWIG por exemplo.

Outra forma, é usar a forma mais simples de 'echo' na view, por exemplo

```
<input id= "IDname" type="text" name="name" value="<?= $_GET['algo']; ?>" />
```

Além disso, você pode melhorar ainda mais esse processo tratando as variáveis antes da exibição na view.

```
<?php

$idCliente = $_GET['id']; // Você trabalha as regras de negócio aqui

// ... 
// e depois na view você só faz a exibição

<input id= "IDname" type="text" name="name" value="<?= $idCliente; ?>" />
```